# Почему может зависать Apache при выполнении file_get_contents?

Tags: apache, php

При выполнении кода на нижеприведённом сайте Денвер зависает. С чем может быть связана проблема?

```
file_get_contents("http://the-system.org/engine/engine.php")
```

Пробовал ограничивать количество считываемых символов, результат тот же.

```
file_get_contents("http://the-system.org/engine/engine.php",NULL,NULL,0,1024);
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема именно с этим сайтом или любым другим тоже ?

попробуйте:

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 3); // максимум 3 секунды на выполнение операции чтения с сокетов.
file_get_contents("http://the-system.org/engine/engine.php");
```

Comment: Не помогает. Проблема именно с этим сайтом :) - вот хочу понять в чём дело. Все остальные сайты отлично парсятся данным приёмом.

Comment: парсится ? А вы код приведите, возможно зацикливается не на file_get_contents а уже при обработке данных. Проверьте это.

Answer (score 0):

права на файл проверь

Comment: Файл на внешнем сайте. Права точно ни при чём.

Comment: внешний сайт может не позволять эту операцию, используй CURL

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка когда объем сильно большой или нет доступа (404) к страничке

Comment: Ограничивал размер вот таким способом
("http://the-system.org/engine/engine.php",NULL,NULL,0,1024);
не помогло :(

Comment: уже писали можно ограничить по времени.  
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 3);  
Или проверить существует ли файл.

Answer (score 0):

используйте [Curl](http://cleverscript.ru/php/scripts-php/51-curl.html)